# how to interpret beta in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I conducted binary logistic regression analysis (DV is measured in yes, no). Among my IVs, One IV is about partnership measured in dichotomous (yes, no) and another IV is population density and measured as (Low=1, average =2, high (reference group) =3).

The output shows that:

- For partnership: $\beta$ value of partnership(1) is .795 while it is significant.
- For population density: $\beta$ values are: low(1) = -.976, average = -.641

I need your help on how to interpret beta values especially the negative signs

Comment: [here](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/) is a nice help page

Comment: The following link might also help: http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/

Comment: Perhaps this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/what-is-the-significance-of-logistic-regression-coefficients might help.